# Is Credentials a must to use WMI to remotely uninstall applications?

Tags: c#

I want to remotely uninstall apps from clients using c#. In all the samples in stocoverflow, WMI is used with credentials. My clients don't have user name and password, so can I still use WMI without credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most remote control type software requires a username and password on the account as a safety precaution.

I would recommend setting up the client PC's with a password protected account, that is used for this purpose, while they can also keep their non-password account to login and do other things.

Opening up something to the outside world carries a security risk, credentials is the least you can do.